# Glue Records, A Records, and NS Records

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, a-record, ns-record, glue-record

I have set up my name server and set the glue records. It's working.

However, I'm not sure if I have everything properly to spec. For example, I currently have a glue record set for `ns1.mydomain.example` set to `192.0.2.4`.

Now, for the authoritative server for `mydomain.example`, I do NOT have an A record for `ns1.mydomain.example` pointing to `192.0.2.4`, nor do I have an NS record for the similar entry.

Should I? I feel like that's unnecessary duplication, but I'm also pretty sure I'm missing something since `dig ns1.mydomain.example` doesn't work, but it does work for other name servers I've tested.

To clarify, I'm asking for best practice. Like I said, it's working, so I'm hesitant to change it unless it's not up to the expected standard.

Comment: Give real names if you want real useful help... There is no best practice here, there is only what works and what does not. Glue "records" are just A/AAAA records at the parent, needed ONLY if nameserver used are in-bailiwick or internal to the registry. So they are needed if `ns1.mydomain.example`is nameserver of `mydomain.example`but they won't be needed in registry of TLD `.test` if it is nameserver of domain `mydomain.test`

Comment: It also helps if we know what DNS server you're running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need the "redundant" NS and A/AAAA records in your zone.  Glue records are only used by resolvers to find the authoritative name servers for a zone, they aren't used as authoritative answers (because glue records aren't authoritative, they're just hints in the right direction).